# Strangeness Conservation

Tags: electromagnetism, standard-model, weak-interaction, strong-force

I am stuck as to how to prove that strangeness is conserved in electromagnetic and strong interactions, while it is not conserved in weak interactions. I know that this can be shown by studying the terms of the standard model Lagrangian, but I have no idea as to how I should proceed.

Comment: Write down all  vertices involving at least one strange quark and a gauge boson.

Comment: Hint: which interactions change quark flavor?